# When I click the Like button, the comment popup window ('flyout') doesn't show

Tags: css, wordpress, facebook-like

I have spend lot of time fixing it. Can you please let me know what am i doing wrong. I know it is related to overflow: visible property. But I have tried to put it almost everywhere in the code but no luck. tried using firebug as well. maybe i am not able to use it correctly.

Below is the link to my site.

http://kunalchichkar.com/2011/05/heir-hunters-on-their-way-are-you-lucky-enough/

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Kunal

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have used some plugin to show social sharing bar above your post. 
Plugin you have used to share post in facebook might have used iframe so comment frame is not being display after user likes the post.

If iframe is used to share any post in facebook, comment popup will not be display. 
See documentation in facebook plugin development link for more detail:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Read FAQ carefully. You can find your question's answer exactly there. There is question and answer for "When I click the Like button, the comment popup window ('flyout') doesn't show. Why?"
Hope, it will be useful for you.